# UIScrollView & UIPageControl - start on specific page in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have implemented an UIScrollView & UIpageControl to display 3 UIViewControllers.
It works very well but I want to start the display on the 2nd UIViewController.

I didn't find yet where is my fault:

```
var pageControl:UIPageControl!
var scrollView:UIScrollView!
var viewtest1:UIViewController!
var viewtest2:UIViewController!
var viewtest3:UIViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialization of UIScrollView
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.scrollView.delegate = self

    // Initialisation of UIPageControl
    self.pageControl = UIPageControl()

    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red:0.325, green:0.667, blue:0.922, alpha: 1)
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // Add different view to the screen in the order from left to right

    self.addChildViewController(self.viewtest1)
    self.addChildViewController(self.viewtest2)
    self.addChildViewController(self.viewtest3)

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    for var i=0; i < self.childViewControllers.count; i++ {
        self.loadScrollViewWithPage(i)

    }

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.page = 0

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.childViewControllers.count

    var viewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController

    if viewController.view.superview != nil {
        viewController.viewWillAppear(true)
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(self.childViewControllers.count), scrollView.frame.size.height)

}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Load Controllers
    var viewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController

    if viewController.view.superview != nil {
        viewController.viewDidAppear(true)
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    var viewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController

    if viewController.view.superview != nil {
        viewController.viewWillDisappear(true)
    }

    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    var viewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController

    if viewController.view.superview != nil {
        viewController.viewDidDisappear(true)
    }

    super.viewDidDisappear(true)
}

func loadScrollViewWithPage(page:Int){
    if page < 0 || page >= self.childViewControllers.count {
        return
    }

    let controller:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[page] as! UIViewController

    if (controller == false) {
        return
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
        var frame:CGRect = self.scrollView.frame
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0
        controller.view.frame = frame
        self.scrollView.addSubview(controller.view)
    }

}

func changePage(sender:AnyObject) -> () {
    var senderControl:UIPageControl = sender as! UIPageControl
    var page:Int = Int(senderControl.currentPage) 

    // update the scroll view to the appropriate page
    var frame:CGRect = self.scrollView.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
    frame.origin.y = 0

    var oldViewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.page] as! UIViewController

    var newViewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController


    oldViewController.viewWillDisappear(true)
    newViewController.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)

    self.pageControlUsed = true

}

override func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var oldViewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.page] as! UIViewController
    var newViewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController

    oldViewController.viewWillDisappear(true)
    newViewController.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.page = self.pageControl.currentPage

}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.pageControlUsed == true /*|| _rotating*/) {
        // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
        return
    }

    var pageWidth:CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.size.width
    var page:Int = Int(floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)
    if (self.pageControl.currentPage != page) {

        var oldViewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[self.pageControl.currentPage] as! UIViewController

        var newViewController:UIViewController = self.childViewControllers[page] as! UIViewController


        oldViewController.viewWillDisappear(true)
        newViewController.viewWillDisappear(true)
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page
        oldViewController.viewDidDisappear(true)
        newViewController.viewDidDisappear(true)

        self.page = page;
    }
}

override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.pageControlUsed = false
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.pageControlUsed = false

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not to dig at your code, but I was wondering why you have set your project up like this? Seems like an easier way would be to use storyboard, setup three ViewControllers with UIScrollViews and just use segues to change from view to view. You could also easily set the initial View Controller to what ever view you wanted

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If not let me know where you are stuck and I will try to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The snippet here is the simplified version of my code but it's exactly set up like this. I did it like this because the uiscrollview is integrated at the head of an uitableviewcontroller. I was thinking by doing programmatically would be easier than using storyboard. 
I have succeed with this line in the viewwillappear :
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 1, 0);

But I would enjoy your solution !!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard set the "viewtest2" to "Is Initial View Controller". That will show that viewController first.

Or you can try in appDelegate :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject :AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewTest2") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```